# PHP how to simply upload video to server

Tags: php, video, upload, mp4

I want to simply upload a video (MP4) to a folder on the website using PHP and be able to retrieve it. I searched several websites and questions on stackoverflow and all of them have not worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is too broad for this site. Please see “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)” for more information.

Comment: [Show your try](http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i-w600/keep-calm-and-show-the-code.jpg)

Comment: I don't exactly have a problem with any specific code, but rather the process of uploading  a video to a server

Comment: Start from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: thank you but this only supports uploading of an image and not a video (i have tried)

Comment: There is not difference. If you [show your code](http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i-w600/keep-calm-and-show-the-code.jpg) and the errors we can help you. Otherwise it is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Without any code examples, it is kinda hard to answer, but here is something you can use as a starting point.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Once you can get the file to upload to your PHP script (in temp storage on the server), you can then use PHP functions to move the file to a folder, or insert it into a database.

Be aware, the example is simple, and not super secure. You will want to enforce limiting mime types and file sizes to start.

If you get some code written and have issues, I would suggest updating your question so we can help.

You may run into a few issues with uploading.

1. Server permissions
2. File Size Limits
3. Folder permissions to put the file.

Note: The example I gave you is for images, but just look through it because obviously you can't use

```
getimagesize()
```

on a video.

You should be able to use this instead:http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

I would first focus on getting a basic, secure uploader working. From there you can do specific video stuff.

Good luck.